# Universal NavBar Links

Tags: php, navbar, nav

So I get that that is a silly beginner question, but I can't figure it out.  Its two parts:

**THE SETUP**
 
So I want to have a universal navbar on my site.  I created a navigation.php file and I am using include on every page.

**THE PROBLEM**
On my index page, it is working great.  However all of my other pages are within a contentFiles folder.  When I navigate from the index page, back to the index page the contentPages, the sub-directory stays in the URL.

To see exactly what it is doing: 
1. Go to http://www.newshongumpto.org
2. Click on News/Calendar > Calendar
3. Click on Home

Any suggestions?  My next questions is how to make this dynamic from my dB, but I think I will attempt that first before coming back.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top navbar-left" role="navigation">
  <div class="nav-container container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs3-navbar-collapse"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span></button>
      <img src="/images/ShongumSkyhawkBird_Green_Brand.png" alt="Shongum Elementary School" class="skyhawk_navimage" width="45" height="56"></div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs3-navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="about.php">About Us</a></li>
<li class="dropdown"> <a href="/membership/membership.php" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Membership <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Benefits of Membership</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="membership/parentform.php">Parent Membership Application</a></li>
            <li><a href="membership/teacherform.php">Teacher Membership Application</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown"> <a href="/programs/programs.php" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Programs <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="/programs/getinvolved.php">Get Involved!</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="/programs/familyportraits.php">Family Portraits</a></li>
            <li><a href="/programs/roomparents.php">Room Parents</a></li>
            <li><a href="/programs/enrichment.php">Skyhawk Enrichment</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown"> <a href="/classes/classes.php" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Classes <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="/classes/kindergarden.php">Kindergarden</a></li>
            <li><a href="/classes/1st.php">1st Grade</a></li>
            <li><a href="/classes/2nd.php">2nd Grade</a></li>
            <li><a href="/classes/3rd.php">3rd Grade</a></li>
            <li><a href="/classes/4th.php">4th Grade</a></li>
            <li><a href="/classes/5th.php">5th Grade</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="store.php">Store</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown"> <a href="/newsCalendar/newscalendar.php" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">News/Calendar <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="/newsCalendar/news.php">News</a></li>
            <li><a href="/newsCalendar/calendar.php">Calendar</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">RSD<b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="https://www.rtnj.org/Page/2444">RAM Alerts</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://www.rtnj.org/domain/162">District Calendar</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://maschiofood.com/shongum-elementary-school/">Lunch Menu (Shongum Only)</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
          <li><form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="749L2346K28NW">
<input type="submit" value="Donate Now »" name="submit" title="Donate to your Shongum PTO Today!" class="paypal_btn">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form> </li>
      </ul>

      <a class="btn btn-default navbar-btn" href="../contentPages/membership/membership.php">Membership Sign-Up</button>
    </a>    </div>
  </div>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `href="index.php"` to `href="/index.php"`

Similarly add slash to all your urls . This way, all your urls will be routed from your website's base url

Answer (score 0):

Relative links did the tricks...  duh... (ugh)...